# EOF Exception in readobect in java

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm getting eof exception when I'm trying to convert byte[] array to a object. The last byte is same in both arrays.

```
 java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
```

Above is the exception. When this kind of exception is occured? Please help

Comment: That is an End OF File Exception
[Class EOFException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html)

Comment: Could you provide more code please and explain in more detail? In general EOFException is thrown when the end of file or stream is reached unexpectedly.

Comment: You aren't building the bye array correctly. Post the code that does it.

Comment: I found the issue. Ty for the replies..............